# How to retreive and display profile pic Android firebase?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-storage

How to retreive and display profile pic of a the current user using uid? I already have the image connect to the users uid with uid, but not sure how to retreive and display.

This is how I upload it to Firebase Storage

```
mProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
    });
```

I have the user click an imageview from there phone storage and upload that image with the current logged in users uid.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
        mainImageURI = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mainImageURI);
            mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            final ProgressDialog proDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
            proDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            proDialog.show();

            String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("newFolder").child(userUid).putFile(mainImageURI);
            uploadTask
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });

            final StorageReference mRef = mStorage.child("Photos").child(mainImageURI.getLastPathSegment());
            mRef.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    proDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    proDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Upload Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a database where you can save image url against the uid. Then retrieve your profil pic using that url from database

Answer (score 0):

store the image url in a document with the uid and all other attribute and the you can retrieve the image using Glide library
https://github.com/bumptech/glide